# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'basemapLayer' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-cli, esri-leaflet

## ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'basemapLayer' of undefined

I have built a very basic application using the Angular CLI. When I build and run the application using `ng serve -o` everything builds successfully. However, when I view the application in Chrome the map portion does not load. Further inspecting the page I see this error in the console.

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'basemapLayer' of undefined`

### Setup

- Angular 4
- Chrome 61
- leaflet 1.2.0
- esri-leaflet 2.1.1
- types/leaflet for 1.2
- types/esri-leaflet for 2.1.

### Steps to reproduce the error:

These steps assume that you already have [angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) installed.

**Steps 1-6 & 10 are done in terminal/cmd prompt window**

1. Create a new application `ng new esriLeafletApp`
2. Navigate to the new application `cd esriLeafletApp`
3. `npm install --save leaflet`
4. `npm install --save esri-leaflet`
5. `npm install --save @types/esri-leaflet`
6. `npm install --save @types/leaflet`
7. Update the contents of the *app.component.ts* file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'esri-leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit () {
    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Streets').addTo(map);
  }
}
```

8. Update the contents of the *app.component.html* file

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
       Welcome to {{title}}!
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

9. Update the contents of the *app.component.css* file

   ```css
   #map {
     height: 500px;
     width: 100%;
   }
   ```
10. Build and run the application `ng serve -o`
11. View the application in Chrome
12. Inspect the code and view the error in the inspector console

### Please Help

Does anyone know why `esri` is `undefined` in the code block `L.esri.basemapLayer('Streets').addTo(map);` and how I might go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue lies with the typings file for esri-leaflet (@types/esri-leaflet), instead of with esri-leaflet itself. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19872) on the DefinitelyTyped github.

### The workaround:

- Remove ESRI typings from package.json and node_modules
- Import esri: `import * as esri from 'esri-leaflet';`
- Use esri directly (i.e. not as an extension of Leaflet).
- Still could use leaflet typings without a problem.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as esri from 'esri-leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit () {
    const map = L.map('map', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 0
    }).setView([51.505, -0.09], 15);

    const esriLayer = esri.basemapLayer('Imagery');
    map.addLayer(esriLayer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this would happen out of the blue for a site not using angular.